# Capacitor's voltage

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, electrostatics, capacitance, potential-energy

Imagine I have two plates that form a capacitor, so the magnitude of the charge in each plate is, let's say, $Q$. So, the force, in respect to the distance $d$, is gonna be:
$$F(d) = k\frac{Q^2}{d^2}$$
So, in order to calculate the **energy** stored in the capacitor, since it's equal the work needed to pull a plate next to the other, I can calculate the energy $E$ by:
$$E = F(d)\cdot d$$
But since $F$ changes with respect to $d$, then I have to integrate $F$, and then multiply by $d$, so:

$$E = \int F(d)dd = \int k\frac{Q^2}{d^2} = kQ^2\int\frac{1}{d^2}dd = -kQ^2\frac{1}{d}$$

So:
$$E = -kQ^2\frac{1}{d} =-k\frac{Q^2}{d}$$

I also know that **`voltage`** is the same as **`energy per charge`**, so:
$$V = \frac{E}{Q} = \frac{-k\frac{Q^2}{d}}{Q} = -k\frac{Q}{d}$$

Is it right?

I don't know, because the capacitance $C$ is $$C = \frac{Q}{V}$$
or $$Q = CV$$
And $E = QV$
Then if I substitute $Q$ inside my **energy** formula, I get:

$$E = -k\frac{CV^2}{d}$$ but the right should be:

$$E = \frac{CV^2}{2}$$

Can somebody help me?

Comment: I'm not sure what the definition of $k$ is. Can you put that in?

Comment: How did you  get the equation for $F(d)$? There might be an error there.

Comment: @SteveB $k$ is the coulomb's constant from the coulomb's law

Comment: @SatwikPasani since the force depends of $d$ (distance) then $F$ is a function dependente of $d$

Comment: @Mr.Zantos. The dependence on d as the function you cite was a part of the question or its derivation was one of the steps of your solution?

Comment: @SatwikPasani if I want to calculate the energy, I must integrate force in $d$. So i've just assumed Force depends of $d$, I just like to write this way, but it's the sabe as integrating just '$F$'

Answer (score 1):

The equation of $F(d)$ you cite ($F(d)=k\frac{Q^2}{d^2}$)is only for two point charges and not for the force in case of two charged plates. If you have two large (theoretically infinite) charged plates, each having surface charge density $\sigma=Q/A$, then the force on any one plate is $\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_o}Q$ and is not dependent on the distance in the case of very large plates.
If you find the potential energy $U$ by integrating this from $0$ to $d$:-
$$\int_0^d \frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}Qdx$$ you will get $\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}Qd$ which then can be rearranged using $C=\frac{\epsilon_0 A}{d}$ to get $U=\frac{Q^2}{2C}$ or $U=\frac 12 CV^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The energy stored in an electric field is given by 
$$ W= \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}∫dr^3 E⃗^ 2(r⃗ )$$

Comment: But I want to get to a equation intuitively